# Retrieving different items from NSUserDefaults depending on the day

Tags: objective-c

Currently I have this code:

```
NSArray *lessons = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"TuesdayLessons"];

NSString *s1 = [lessons objectAtIndex:0];
self.lesson1.text = s1;

NSString *s2 = [lessons objectAtIndex:1];
self.lesson2.text = s2;

NSString *s3 = [lessons objectAtIndex:2];
self.lesson3.text = s3;

NSString *s4 = [lessons objectAtIndex:3];
self.lesson4.text = s4;

NSString *s5 = [lessons objectAtIndex:4];
self.lesson5.text = s5;

NSString *s6 = [lessons objectAtIndex:5];
self.lesson6.text = s6;
```

This grabs the objects in an array and puts them into lables on my view controller. This needs to be done depending on what day it is. For example, if the day is Tuesday, the `objectForKey` would be as it is (`objectForKey:@"TuesdayLessons"`). But if the day were Wednesday, I would want

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"WednesdayLessons"]
```

I need to make my application check what day it is and use this day in the `objectForKey:` call.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the current day name with:

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"EEEE"];
NSString *today = [df stringFromDate:now];
```

Then will return something like "Monday" or "Tuesday". Then you can do:

```
NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@Lessons", today];
```

That will return for example "MondayLessons", which you can use to retrieve the array:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:key];
```

One recommendation: It would be better to use the number of the day (for example, 0=Sunday, 1=Monday, etc...) because of course, day names are different in different languages, in case a user decides to change the language of the device.

Comment: These names are keys in userdefaults. They are not visible to the user. Translating them to a different language would be the height of stupidity. And it would break things if your German teacher decided to switch the language of his device from English to German and back.

Comment: I meant to say that he shouldn't use localized day names as keys. Like you said, if the user switches language, store data will not be accessible.